# Using odbc_result to display multiple table select statement

Tags: php, ms-access, odbc

I have a query :

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM LAF_INFO, SIGNATURE_INFO WHERE LAF_INFO.LAF_NO = SIGNATURE_INFO.LAF_NO";
```

It brings the data but I cannot figure out how to display it in PHP.

```
$rs=odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
if (!$rs) {
  exit("Error in Database Connection");
}
 while (odbc_fetch_row($rs)) {  
         $date_raw = odbc_result($rs, "LAF_INFO.DATE_LAF");
         echo $date_raw
   }
```

It gives error.

```
//Warning: odbc_result() [function.odbc-result]: Field LAF_INFO.DATE_LAF not found in path
```

The table has field `DATE_LAF`. It works fine if I just use one table for select.

any idea how to display.

Comment: Have you tried using just `odbc_result($rs, "DATE_LAF")`?

Comment: yah i have tried odbc_result($rs, "DATE_LAF"); | odbc_result($rs, "LAF_INFO.DATE_LAF"); | odbc_result($rs, 1);. It prints a column when i write 1, but for other columns if i put 0,1,2,3,4,5 it gives error     //Warning: odbc_result() [function.odbc-result]: SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Cursor Library] Positioned request cannot be performed because result set was generated by a join condition, SQL state SL002 in SQLGetData

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting DATE_LAF, therefore you should change your code to:

```
$rs=odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
if (!$rs) {
  exit("Error in Database Connection");
}
 while (odbc_fetch_row($rs)) {  
         $date_raw = odbc_result($rs, "DATE_LAF");
         echo $date_raw
   }
```

Comment: already tried it, it does not work. is there a different parameter in odbc_result($r, ???); for join tables?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? What do you actually experience?

Comment: as i said in the comment above it gives error. I have tried all this, i have tried odbc_result($rs, "DATE_LAF"); | odbc_result($rs, "LAF_INFO.DATE_LAF"); | odbc_result($rs, 1);. It prints a column when i write 1, but for other columns if i put 0,1,2,3,4,5 it gives error //Warning: odbc_result() [function.odbc-result]: SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Cursor Library] Positioned request cannot be performed because result set was generated by a join condition, SQL state SL002 in SQLGetData. SO i think there is something that i need to do in odbc_result() function for join tables.